# .ipa files automatically converts to .ipa.zip format in ios 16.1

Tags: iphone, zip, ipa, sideloading

When trying to download .ipa file of a application in ios 16.1 from mediafire the files which is uploaded on the mediafire is in the format of the .ipa file and the file which i am getting in the download is in the format .ipa.zip and it cant be executed in the alt server

I was trying to unzip the file but it appears to become corrupt because its not completely zip file which could be extracted . so what should i do to download the file as .ipa format and use it without any compression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try downloading the .ipa file from the different website . or you can try is to download sideloadly software on your pc and connect apple id and directly from your pc you can sideload the apps without the use of alt server.

Answer (score 0):

The ipa file gets converted to from .ipa to .zip because of ios 16 new security patches and or it could be the error in the file or it could be corrupted . Don't try to extract the file cause ios does not convert the .ipa file while downloading . I think you should try to remove the last .zip extension from the ipa file and then try sideloading the apps